# Given two yes/no fields, how can I use JavaScript to make the field 2 value checked "Yes" whenever the field 1 value is checked "Yes"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, checkbox

If Field 1 is checked "Yes" then Field 2 should be checked "Yes"

This is what I've been trying so far:

Field 1:

```
<div class="entire">
<div class="col3"><label class="label-right">||FIELDTAG Field1||Question15||ENDFIELDTAG||&nbsp;</label></div>
<div class="col9"><input type="radio" name="Field1" id="Question15yes" value="Yes" onclick="Check()">Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Field1" value="No" onclick="Check()">No</div>
```

Field 2:

```
<div class="entire">
<div class="col3"><label class="label-right">||FIELDTAG Field2||Question16||ENDFIELDTAG||&nbsp;</label></div>
<div class="col9"><input type="radio" name="Field2" id="Question16yes" value="Yes" onclick="Check()">Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Field2" value="No" onclick="Check()">No</div>
```

I was trying something as simple as this js below, but I'm definitely missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script language="JavaScript">    
function Check()  {
$("#Question15yes").click(function(){
     if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
         $("#Question16yes").val("Yes");
     }
        }
      });
    }      
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including JQuery in your page.

To bind your event, you need to wait that the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is [fully loaded](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), else you would try to use an element that doesn't exist yet.

```
<script language="JavaScript">    
    $(function() {
      $(".question-checkbox").click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
          console.log($(this));
        }
      });
    });     
</script>
```

Also, you might want to change the JQuery selector from ID to class, so that you can use the same code for all similar checkboxes.

Put a `.question-checkbox` class on the inputs, and remove all onclicks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for a single checkbox with the class name "example":

```
 $('input.example').on('change', function() {
  $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `check` on every click. Once document loads, call it once.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  $("input[type='radio']").on("click", function(){
    if($("#Question15yes").is(':checked'))
      $("#Question16yes").prop("checked", true);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entire">
  <div class="col3">
    <label class="label-right">||FIELDTAG Field1||Question15||ENDFIELDTAG||&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
  <div class="col9">
    <input type="radio" name="Field1" id="Question15yes" value="Yes">
      Yes&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Field1" value="No" >No
  </div>

<div class="entire">
  <div class="col3">
    <label class="label-right">||FIELDTAG Field2||Question16||ENDFIELDTAG||&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
  <div class="col9">
    <input type="radio" name="Field2" id="Question16yes" value="Yes">
    Yes&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Field2" value="No">
    No
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I don't call the check on each click, would a user be able to change field 2 to "No" manually? I was thinking it needed to call the check again to force it back to "Yes" if they try to make field 2 "No"